# How to dump the entire GDB session to a file, including commands I type and their output?

Tags: gdb

In bash, I can use the `script` command, which dumps everything that shows on the shell to a file, including:

- commands typed
- PS1 line
- stdout and stderr of commands

What is the equivalent in gdb?

I tried to run `shell script` from inside GDB, but after I hit return, I was in the shell and lost the shell prompt and could not run command any more. Moreover I could not use ctrl+c or ctrl+\ to exit. I needed to force kill the `/bin/login tty2` to exit.

Comment: Can you post an example what you tried? A screenshot with a short explanation? Also, what does "In the shell,I could use script to extract text" mean? Do you run a script on a file to extract text or do you use shell redirection (>) to extract text?

Comment: script is the command to log the shell output to file typescript.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I didn't know about `script`, it is a (horribly generically named) executable from linux-util. I've explained what it does a bit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to log GDB's output, you can use the [GDB logging output commands](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html#Logging-Output), eg.

```
set logging file mylog.txt
set logging on
```

If you want to redirect your program's output to a file, you can use a redirect, eg.

```
run myprog > mylog.txt
```

see the [chapter on program IO in the GDB manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Input_002fOutput.html#Input_002fOutput) for more information

Comment: the link is broken and it should be http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html#Logging-Output.

Answer (score 3):

- Create a text file, i.e. `gdbCommands.txt`, with the following commands

`set logging on my_log_file\nbt 10\nq`

`bt 10`, indicates the number of lines (function calls) we need from the backtrace, in our example is 10 lines.

- Execute gdb using the following command, assuming a core dump file core.2345

`gdb -x gdbCommands.txt myApp core.2345`

- Open `my_log_file` and inspect backtrace!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, folks may down vote or flag this answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 2):

I have logging enabled using:

```
set trace-commands on
set pagination off
set logging file $log
```

and show logging reports (to both to terminal and file):

```
  +show logging
     Currently logging to mylog.
     Logs will be appended to the log file.
     Output will be logged and displayed
```

If I print the value of a variable that also gets logged (to both to terminal and file):

```
+p myvar
$2 = 0
```

But if I do command like where or “info b” all I get logged to the file is:

```
+where
+info b
```

Anyone know why or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I too have backtraces printing on stdout but not getting captured in gdb's logfile

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the GDB documentation. Search for "Canned Sequences of Commands". There is a way to save GDB commands in a file and run them with the `source` command and you can use some GDB commands in these scripts to print information available to GDB (like `echo`, `output` and `printf`).

If you want that output in a file, use `set logging file FILE`.